# Barebones vim with `nocp`

Tags: vim

I am trying to load a barebones vim. So I defined a `~/.slimvimrc` which has the following contents

`syntax on
 map q :q <cr>`

Then I load vim using `vim -u ~/.slimvimrc`. When I press `q` I expect vim to close because of the mapping above. However, vim just 'sits' on the command line printing `q<CR>` and waits for input.

However , if I add `nocp` setting to the above `vimrc` :

`syntax on
 set nocp
 map q :q <cr>`

the mapping works fine. I looked up the documentation of `nocp`, but unable to locate it's relation with `<CR>`. Can you point me the right place?

Comment: In addition, you need to look `:help cpoptions` in particular `:he cpo-k` and `:he cpo-<`

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping doesn't work in "compatible mode" because `<` is not recognized as starting a key code.

Your `~/.slimvimrc` should look like this:

```
set nocompatible
syntax on
nnoremap q :q<CR>
```

Note the specificity of `nnoremap`:

- the first `n` means "normal mode",
- `nore` means "non-recursive",

and the removed space between `:q` and `<CR>`.

Anyway, `q<char>` is used to start a recording in register `<char>`. That feature is awesome! Overriding it with a custom mapping doesn't sound like a very good idea.

Also, you can call Vim with the `-N` argument to force `'nocompatible'`:

```
$ vim -N -u ~/.slimvimrc
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that in vi-compatible mode, Vim does not parse the special keys like `<CR>`; this is controlled by the `'cpoptions'` setting, in particular `:help cpo-k` and `:help cpo-<`.

Why is Vim in vi-compatible mode? Usually, Vim sets `'nocompatible'` when a `~/.vimrc` is found, but your use of `-u` turns this off. From `:help 'compatible'`:

> When a vimrc or gvimrc file is found while Vim is starting up,
>   this option is switched off, and all options that have not been
>   modified will be set to the Vim defaults.  Effectively, this means
>   that when a vimrc or gvimrc file exists, Vim will use the Vim
>   defaults, otherwise it will use the Vi defaults.  (Note: **This doesn't
>   happen** for the system-wide vimrc or gvimrc file, nor **for a file given
>   with the -u argument**).

The solution is to explicitly `set nocompatible` at the top of your `~/.slimvimrc`, or pass `-N` in addition to `-u`.